# How to Access and Utilize Audit History for Flow in Dataverse?

Tags: dynamics-crm, power-automate, powerapps, dataverse

Basically, my question is, where is the audit table and how to work with it? And is it even possible?

[image: Audit History example]

For context, I need to create a Flow that sets a field (let's call it HUMAN_CHECK) to TRUE so can make a view filtering by it, and humans can later manually go over these records and do some accounting work.

The tricky part now, is the conditions required to set HUMAN_CHECK to TRUE. Any record in the last three months that have had a specific set of accounting related fields modified, should have HUMAN_CHECK set to TRUE.

My first idea was to simply set a condition in my fetchXML to having ModifiedOn equal or greater to 3 Months in the past.
The issue here, is that this filter selects all modifications and there are just too many that are not relevant and the list the humans have to go over gets too big. There is also a specific field that is responsible for many of the modifications that are not relevant: ENDE.

I realized that the audit history tracks changes and data about which Field was modified. My Idea now was to use it so i can filter modified records where the change was NOT to the ENDE field. I searched everywhere and I can't for the life of me find out how to work with it.
I assumed there would be an audit table but I can't find it. Is there just no way to work with it with the dataverse actions? There's not much help in the docs besides a mention of API but I'm not sure how could i use it in my situation as well.

Comment: The audit data is stored in the table called Audit and you can get detail info in the column changedata. As changedata is a JSON string and you will need to parse it, I would suggest another way: Add a new field Accounting Modified On, when the related accounting field gets updated, set the Accounting Modified On to the trigger time, and query the data you need by this field would be easier than query audit.